# How to re-use Spree Image uploading system in another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree, solidus

I am learning ruby on rails (Version 4.2).
I am working on spree making a web commerce.
I have to make a Inspiration page which will contain description(globalize system), a video link, published_on and multiple images.
I don't go to use paperclip/carrierwave gem or other gem.

I want to use spree product image uploading system. I have made a Inspiration Model and Inspiration_images model.

Inspiration.rb

```
class Inspiration < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :video_link, presence: true # validation for video attributes
  # attributes for description field with globalize
  translates :description
  globalize_accessors locales: [:en, :de, :fr], attributes: [:description]
# iamges
  has_many :images, -> { order(:position) }, as: :viewable, dependent: :destroy, class_name: "Spree::Image"

  # scopes for inspiration
  scope :publishable, -> { where('published_on <= ?', Time.zone.today) }
end
```

Inspiration_images.rb:

```
class InspirationImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inspiration
end
```

But now, How to make a form and controller(create method) regarding using this model ?
I want to make this as like as Spree Image uploading system.
Please help me.

Comment: you can use normal `create` for upload new image and make sure you permit param for image

Comment: I want to store my all inspiration images in spree assets table using spree image model.

Comment: @Engr.TanbirHasan Did you ever answer this question? I am wondering the answer. Cheers.